# SimpleDateFormat Exception

Tags: java, exception

Hi I am using SimpleDateFormat for parsing and comparing two dates from strings. here is my code

```
private static int compareDates(String lineFromFile, String givenDate) throws ParseException, IllegalArgumentException
  {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date dateFromfile = sdf.parse(tmp);
    Date givenDateTime = sdf.parse(givenDate);
    if (dateFromfile.equals(givenDateTime))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (dateFromfile.before(givenDateTime))
    {
        return 1;
    }

        return -1;
    }
```

And here is a main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
        int result = compareDates("00:45:44", "09:35:56");
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }

}
```

This works normally when I am passing valid arguments, but ! want to have an exception when passing for example "28:40:04", now I have an exceptions only when passing as an argument string containing letters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set lenient to `false` (the default behavior is lenient):

```
sdf.setLenient(false);
```

See [What is the use of "lenient "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606387/what-is-the-use-of-lenient) and the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29):

> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

Comment: I am trying this, but it the result is the same

Comment: Actually it is lenient by default, and you need to set it to false: sdf.setLenient(false);