# Why can I parse "2015-18-32" with SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I was trying to answer a question, and I prepared a little example, expecting to offer some success and error messages, after having the code working I tried:

**CODE**

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
// correct format in string but totally wrong data for a date.
String curDate = "2015-18-32";
Date parsedDate = null;
try {
    parsedDate = format.parse(curDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {}

System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

**OUTPUT**

> Sat Jul 02 00:00:00 CEST 2016

[DEMO HERE](https://ideone.com/fFXmoK)

I understand resulting date is just the valid one (2015-12-31) adding 6 months and 1 day to the date, but that does not seem correct for me. Am I misunderstanding `SimpleDateFormat`?

- Shouldn't this code give an exception or error?

Comment: IIRC `SimpleDateFormat` is lenient by default, i.e. it just rolls over and adds excess days and months.

Comment: It is lenient parsing which uses heuristics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#isLenient%28%29. This feature can be turned off by `df.setLenient(false)`

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606387/what-is-the-use-of-lenient)

Comment: See also [How to sanity check a date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java).

Comment: Just wondering: how much previous research have you done?

Comment: @Jägermeister enough.... non having english as mother language does not help.... lenient is a word i never heard, is difficult to get some info when you don't know the word are you searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the format by calling setLenient(false).

This actually adds 6 months and 2 days to the date with the out-of-range figures for month and day in month, ending up with July 2nd 2016.

See also [jwenting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279236/jwenting)'s comment below on `java.util.Calendar` leniency.

Comment: more strictly, the underlying Calendar instance is the one that's lenient: "Calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient and non-lenient. When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as February 1. "

Comment: @jwenting thanks, added a reference to your comment.

Comment: @jwenting and Mena, thanks, I had to translate your answer to understand lenient... :S, my problem was the english in this case, not misunderstanding the code.... ;)

Comment: @JordiCastilla `lenitivo`? `indulgente`? or `indulgent`? :)

Comment: I knew indulgent yes, because indulgente is also a word in spanish... but lenitivo or similar does not exists for this case.... word [lenitivo](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=lenitivo) has not this meaning in spanish...  Check [here synonims of indulgente](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/indulgente)

Comment: @JordiCastilla aha thanks.