# ParseException never thrown

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, exception

I have a `@Service` annotated service class method `createShiftPlan(int numberOfEmployees, int startingMonth, int year)` inside which I am using `SimpleDateFormat` class's `parse()` method.

How can I test for parse exceptions with integer inputs here?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Set [`SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) to [disable lenient parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606387/what-is-the-use-of-lenient/7606437#7606437) and supply a non-existing date e.g. 35th of April. With lenient disabled this will throw a `ParseException` instead of silently fixing the date.